# Adding series programmatically to a Dundas TreeMap

Tags: c#, asp.net, dundas

I'm trying to programmatically add a series to a Dundas TreeMap but I'm getting a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error. This error looks to be a bug in Dundas, but I was wondering if anyone has tried/managed to do this?

If I add the series in declaratively then at all works fine.

Comment: post your source code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the TreeMap will quite happily have an empty series if they are declaratively declared, but if any are programatically added, then all series (even declaritive ones) have to have a data point. This worked for me.